# PL SQL cursor for/while loop procedures

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi need some help regarding some works I've got assigned with having a little trouble figuring it out.

```
CREATE TABLE "DET_CAM" 
    ("EQUIPMENT_ID" NVARCHAR2(100),
    "EQUIPMENT_TYPE_ID" NUMBER(6),
    "LINK_ID" NUMBER(9), 
    "NODE_FR_ID" NUMBER(9),
    "NODE_TO_ID" NUMBER(9),
    "ROAD_NAME" NVARCHAR2(64),  
    "DIRECTION" NUMBER(1)
    );
```

[Insert Data file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7oznznyhpfpomx8/TestCam%28Create%29.sql?dl=0)

Created a for loop to cycle through Main Equipment/Links. With use of another 2 loops with parameter how can I find out what's the next or previous blocks that come before and after the main block.

[Link flow how the logic should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCjjp.png)

```
Declare
    -- Cursors --
    Cursor c_MainLink 
    is 
        Select equipment_id, link_id, node_fr_id, node_to_id, road_name, direction
        From DET_CAM
        where 1=1 and equipment_type_id = 113;
    
    -- Downstream Cursor with parameter --
    Cursor c_downlink (p_dn_node_to_id NUMBER, p_dn_direction NUMBER)
    is
        Select a.node_to_id, a.direction, a.equipment_id, a.link_id, a.road_name, a.location_id
        From DET_CAM a
        where 1=1 and equipment_type_id = 113 and a.node_to_id = p_dn_node_to_id and a.direction = p_dn_direction
        Order by road_name asc, direction asc;
        
    -- Upstream Cursor with parameter --
    Cursor c_uplink (p_up_node_fr_id NUMBER, p_up_direction NUMBER)
    is
        Select a.node_fr_id, a.direction, a.equipment_id, a.link_id, a.road_name, a.location_id
        From DET_CAM a
        where 1=1 and equipment_type_id = 113 and a.node_fr_id = p_up_node_fr_id and a.direction = p_up_direction
        Order by road_name asc, direction asc;
        
Begin
    for m_equip in c_MainLink loop
            for ds_equip in c_downlink(m_equip.node_fr_id, m_equip.direction) loop
                for up_equip in c_uplink(m_equip.node_to_id, m_equip.direction) loop
                    dbms_output.put_line('Downstream (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): '||ds_equip.equipment_id||' | '||ds_equip.link_id||' | '||ds_equip.road_name||
                                         ' | Main (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): '||ds_equip.equipment_id||' | '||ds_equip.link_id||' | '||ds_equip.road_name||
                                         ' | Upstream (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): '||up_equip.equipment_id||' | '||up_equip.link_id||' | '||up_equip.road_name
                                         );
                end loop; 
            end loop;            
    end loop;
End;

/* Actual Result:*/
Downstream (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): DET_516323 | 34854 | BISHAN FLYOVER | Main (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): DET_516323 | 34854 | BISHAN FLYOVER | Upstream (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): DET_516325 | 34637 | BISHAN FLYOVER
Downstream (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): DET_566338 | 167815 | TUAS VIADUCT | Main (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): DET_566338 | 167815 | TUAS VIADUCT | Upstream (equip_ID, Link_ID, RN): DET_566336 | 167817 | TUAS VIADUCT
```

/* Expected Result:*/

[SQL Combine table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLxXG.png)

Img Example: [Display both Downstream & Upstream links of an associated equipment that has been selected along with both the equipment details and road name of those links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eK4XF.png)

Both up and downlink block should be identical to one another just one is the reverse to the other, at least from my understanding of the ask.
What's happening now is that its show the blocks that are directly connected to each other however if there is a hole between 2 blocks it will not show the Next/Previous block after the missing block (which is what I need).

*Note that the links and node ids are not in sequence.... and I think this is one of the main reason why I'm finding it difficult to get it to work.

Comment: Suggestion - give us the CREATE TABLE and INSERT commands so we can replicate the setup on our own systems.  That gives us a lot more chance of helping

Comment: added in the create table as well as the insert data basically summarized data of the above select statement used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 DECLARE
  CURSOR c_product
  IS
    SELECT 
        product_name, list_price
    FROM 
       products 
    ORDER BY 
    list_price DESC;
BEGIN
  FOR r_product IN c_product
  LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line( r_product.product_name || ': $' ||  r_product.list_price);        
 END LOOP;
END;
```